# jquery find not working when looping through variable

Tags: jquery, class, find

I can't see what's wrong with the next javascript function.

```
function tapHandler( tabId, divContents ){

    var activeTab = divContents.find('.active-tab-content');    
    if(activeTab.length > 0){
        activeTab.removeClass('active-tab-content').addClass('tab-content');
    }   
    divContents.children('#'+tabId+'-tcontent').addClass('active-tab-content').removeClass('tab-content');

}
```

The jquery find function doesn't work (and I'm afraid that might be my fault).

When I replace the body of the previous function by

```
divContents.each(function(){

    //Clicked tab : Add class active-tab-content
    if(this.id == tabId + "-tcontent"){

        $(this).addClass("active-tab-content").removeClass('tab-content');

    //For the others, if was active before, remove active-tab-content           
    }else{

        if($(this).hasClass("active-tab-content")){
            $(this).removeClass("active-tab-content").addClass('tab-content');  
        }           
    }
});
```

It works. It means every css class I was looking for in the first version of the function exists. But I can't find it. 
The function is called from here:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    $(".tabs-container").each(function() {

        //Get tab's content
        var tabsContent  = $( this ).children( ".tc-holder" ).find('.tab-content');

        //Get tabs
        var tabsMenu =  $( this ).children( ".tab-set" ).find('.tab');;


        tabsMenu.each(function () {

            $( this).click( function(){
                tapHandler(this.id, tabsContent);
            });

        });         
    }); 
});
```

And the HTML code is:

```
            <div class="tabs-container">

                <div data-role="navbar" class="tab-set">

                        <ul>
                            <li id="firstTab" class="tab"><a href="#firstTab-tcontent">One</a></li>
                            <li id="secondTab" class="tab"><a href="#secondTab-tcontent">Two</a></li>
                            <li id="thirdTab" class="tab"><a href="#thirdTab-tcontent">Three</a></li>                           
                        </ul>

                </div><!-- /navbar -->


                <div class="tc-holder">

                    <div id="firstTab-tcontent" class="tab-content">
                        First tab               
                    </div>
                    <div id="secondTab-tcontent" class="tab-content">
                        Second Tab              
                    </div>
                    <div id="thirdTab-tcontent" class="tab-content">
                        Third Tab               
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `divContents` inside your click handler is effectively:

```
$('.tabs-container').children(".tc-holder").find('.tab-content');
```

The above returns an array of child nodes instead of an array comprising a single parent node in which you can find the child nodes; to search the array you need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `.find()`:

```
var activeTab = divContents.filter('.active-tab-content');
```

Also, I would suggest simplifying your event handler registration code:

```
tabsMenu.on('click', function() {
    tapHandler(this.id, tabsContent);
});
```

Comment: Ok, ok! You're right. So the root node was missing and that's why I cannot use the filter. I've also modified the handler registration code. Thanks again. I've already accepted and upvoted your answer :-D

Comment: @MiGU Yes, it was missing a common parent node :) glad it helped!